# Como posso fazer para mostrar um conteúdo somente quando seleciono uma input type=radio

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, input

Estou fazendo um projeto e gostaria e gostaria de saber como posso fazer para o "conteudo a" aparecer somente quando for flegado o input "A" e da mesma forma com o B, utilizando o jquery

```html
 <input class="opcaoa" type="radio" name="opcao" value="A" checked="checked"> A
   <input class="opcaob" type="radio" name="opcao" value="B" > B

   <div class="text_a"><p>conteudo a</p></div>
   <div class="text_b"><p>conteudo b</p></div>
```

Comment: Está aí....aprendi uma palavra nova.

Comment: @AugustoVasques rachei! rsrsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa usar classes diferentes para uma coleção de elementos semelhantes. Para simplificar, só coloque `class` nas divs, e a mesma classe nas duas:

```
<div class="text"><p>conteudo a</p></div>
<div class="text"><p>conteudo b</p></div>
```

Você pode selecionar os radios pelo `name`, já que são iguais:

```
$("[name='opcao']")
```

Como o primeiro radio já vem checado, você deve esconder apenas o segundo no CSS:

```
.text:not(:nth-of-type(1)){
   display: none;
}
```

O seletor `:not(:nth-of-type(1))` exclui da regra o primeiro elemento da classe `.text`.

Depois com jQuery você pega o índice do radio alterado com `.index()` e mostra a div com a classe `.text` que possui o mesmo índice do radio que chamou o evento `change`.

> Não coloquei um snippet aqui porque dá bug no `.index()`. Teste neste
>   [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29xdz63k/).

**CSS:**

```
/* esconde apenas o primeiro elemento da classe */
.text:not(:nth-of-type(1)){
   display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="opcao" value="A" checked="checked"> A
<input type="radio" name="opcao" value="B" > B

<div class="text"><p>conteudo a</p></div>
<div class="text"><p>conteudo b</p></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

   $("[name='opcao']").on("change", function(){
      $(".text").hide(); // esconde tudo
      var idx = $(this).index(); // pega o índice do radio
      $(".text:eq("+idx+")").show(); // mostra a classe .text pelo índice
   });

});
```